# What is written on your second passport if the first passport is filled?

Tags: passports, international-travel, paperwork

I understand that if a person travels internationally for a while, in due course of time, the passport would be filled. In which case he would need to apply to the passport office to get a second and so on and so forth. What is written on the second passport (or whatever number the passport it is.)

The easiest similie to give in this place would be say like a bank passbook, where once its filled, on the second pass-book it will just carry forward your last credit/debit balance and start from there. Does anybody how it works with passports ?

Comment: What do you mean exactly? A passport isn't like a bank passbook (nor are passbooks really used anymore in many countries, but I digress). They just issue you a new passport (some countries can add more pages before it gets to that stage) and you start using it. A passport isn't meant to be some kind of unbroken travel record; people get new passports for all sorts of reasons: the old one expired, the old one was lost/stolen, they gained a new citizenship, the owner changed their name, etc...

Comment: I'll add that it is generally not a "second passport" but simply a new passport. Most countries that I am familiar with only allow people to hold one passport from that country at a time except under certain special circumstances (e.g. holders of both a standard and an official/diplomatic passport, people who frequently need to travel and apply for visas may be allowed to have two since their passport is unavailable while visa applications are processed, people visiting countries that will refuse entry if there are certain foreign stamps in their passport).

Comment: Many countries do issue second passports... but not if the first one is filled (in which case you simply replace it, like you would do when it expires). You get a second passport if you travel a lot and might need to leave your passport with a consulate for visa processing while travelling on the other one or have to go to countries that don't like each other's stamps (say Israel and Lebanon).

Comment: @Relaxed Do you know whether these second passports include any special notation to indicate that they bearer holds another valid passport?

Comment: @phoog - One would think not.  Many folks get a 2nd passport so that they can travel to countries not on friendly terms with each other.  Immigration in those countries could demand to see the primary passport if the second one is marked as such.

Comment: @phoog I don't but I vaguely recall reading somewhere that French second passports had a different number of pages. I suspect that marking them too obviously as such could defeat the purpose (especially with respect to incompatible destinations).

Comment: @phoog German second passports are valid for only six years compared to the usual ten years. It's obvious if you know that which decreases its usefulness a bit.

Comment: In my case, when my passport was full, I got an "extension", that is, extra pages stuck inside the passport.  I had two such extensions for the same passport.

Comment: @Lobachevsky what country is that? The only country I know of that does that is the US, which has discontinued the practice.

Comment: @phoog - other countries used to allow addition of extra pages, but I think the US was the last to stop issuing them.  I sort of recall reading something about it now being agreed upon internationally and due to the imbedded chips (perhaps chip data includes number of pages issued?).

Comment: @Tom interesting, I will check my passport chip with my phone to see whether it has that information encoded. I would have thought it was discontinued for security reasons, like maybe it makes it easier to modify passports fraudulently somehow.

Comment: Hard to say why for sure. But now that the US has discontinued adding pages, several times entering the US I was asked ... where did you get the extra pages? (I added two sets before they stopped the service)

Comment: Although not really related to the question, some countries allow you the option to request a bigger passport (with more pages) and also more than one valid passport.

Comment: @phoog It was the US, and it was 20+ years ago

Comment: @Tom my (non-US) passport does not seem to report its page count on the chip; there's a segment of the data I cannot read because the app I'm using doesn't support the proper security protocol, but the spec for that section doesn't mention page count, either.  I can't get my phone to read the chip on my US passport at all, for some reason.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When your passport is filled, you get a new one, new number and the old one is cancelled. They do not "continue".

If you have long term visas in your old passport, you can bring the old passport as well as the new one when you travel to those destinations.